# Ping specific web addresses?

Tags: bash, ping, https

I'm making a bash script to ping a certain web address.  The problem is, when I say:
`ping https://www.dictionary.com/browse/word`

then ping says
`ping: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/word: Name or service not known`
Can somebody please help me with this?  What is a program that I can use to ping an https server.
I have to have the slashes there because I want to ping that certain page.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: One cannot `ping` a page. `ping` is only responded to by the host system, `www.dictionary.com`. Also, since `ping` uses ICMP, not TCP/IP, specifying `https://` is ineffective.

Comment: You can't ping a certain page.  You can only ping the web address itself.

Comment: Man... that really bites.

Comment: yes. `man`. See: `man ping`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `httping`:

```
httping https://www.dictionary.com/browse/word
```

If you want to check if your word exists, you need to specify, that only Status 200 is OK.

```
httping -m -o 200 https://www.dictionary.com/browse/word
```

And maybe add `-c 1` to exit after 1 probe and `-l` to avoid the Info message that SSL was auto enabled.

Output:

```
$ httping -l -m -o 200 -c1 https://www.dictionary.com/browse/word
69,734001
$ httping -l -m -o 200 -c 1 https://www.dictionary.com/browse/not_existing_word
-1
```

---

Install via

```
sudo apt install httping
```

---

Alternative, if `httping` is not available, **of course** it is possible with `curl` to [print the status code of a request](https://superuser.com/a/442395) only.

```
$ curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" https://www.dictionary.com/browse/word
200
$ curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" https://www.dictionary.com/browse/not_existing_word
301
```

Answer (score 0):

Ping only understands hostnames and ip-addresses. So in your example it should be:

```
ping www.dictionary.com
```

But even this isn't sure to work, because icmp packets (which ping is a part of) might be blocked in router or firewalls along the way to the destination.